# Enumerable.Range() iteration index

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to assign Iteration index to i in the following LINQ code:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(x => new { i = iteration index }).ToList();
```

Comment: To be clear, what specifically do you mean by iteration index? do you mean `var list = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(x => new { i = x }).ToList();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going from 0 to *n*, the iteration index would be equivalent to the range variable `x` from your sample.

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(x => new { i = x }).ToList();
```

If you were using a different range (notably, one not starting with 0), you could use the overload of `Select` that pulls in the index as a second input.

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(10, n).Select((x, index) => new { i = index }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this:-

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select((v, i) => new { Value = v, Index = i });
```

You can manipulate `i` the way you want!

For example:-

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select((v, i) => new { Value = v, Index = i % 2 });

foreach (var x in list)
{
      Console.WriteLine("Value: {0} \t Index : {1}", x.Value, x.Index);
}
```